# After upgrading to Xcode 11 URL's for Bundle resource doesn't work anymore

Tags: swift, xcode11

I upgraded Xcode to Version 11.0 (11A420a) and part of code doesn't work as before. I want to copy folder from Bundle to TemporaryDirectory.

```
    func makeHtmlFile (type: InvoiceType?) -> URL {
        let identifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
        let cacheDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()  + "\(identifier)/Website/"
        let cacheURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: cacheDirectory )
        let websiteUrl = URL(fileReferenceLiteralResourceName: "Website")
        do {
            try FileManager().copyItem(at: websiteUrl, to: cacheURL)
        } catch let error { 
            print ("Copy \(error)\n\tWebsite: \(websiteUrl)\n\tCache:\(cacheURL)")
        }
        ...
    }
```

In Xcode 10 this part of code could find folder `/Website` inside bundle and `temporary directory` in `/var/folders/....`, but after upgrade prints an error:

```
Copy Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “Website” doesn’t exist."
```

Paths displayed in error message exists, I can go there by copying them from an error message and pasting in `Finder -> Go -> Go to Folder`. Does somebody know what was changed after upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved problem at least for myself. Instead of using `NSTemporaryDirectory()` I used `FileManager().temporaryDirectory` for temporary files URL and

```
let tempDirectory = FileManager().temporaryDirectory
if let websiteURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Website", withExtension: nil) {
    let cacheURL = tempDirectory.appendingPathComponent(websiteURL.lastPathComponent, isDirectory: true)
    ...
}
```

Seems to work as before upgrade.